# Is there any bonus for collecting all the rings on a level?

Tags: sonic-the-hedgehog

Can all the rings be collected before the end of the level?
Does anything special happen if you collect them all?

How many rings are on the first level?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There is no bonus for having all the rings other than maximizing your points (100 per ring). The only ring-associated bonus is the [Giant Ring](http://info.sonicretro.org/Giant_Ring#Sonic_1_and_Sonic_CD) that grants access to a Special Stage. The Giant Ring requires you to be carrying 50 rings when you finish the level.

Green Hill Zone, Act I has 225 rings [(source)](http://info.sonicretro.org/Green_Hill_Zone), and as far as I know you can collect them all.

Comment: Also, you get a new life for every 100 rings you collect.

Comment: You only get a new life for 100 and 200 rings. After that, you no longer get lives. It's reproducible if you use the Debug Mode cheat code.

Comment: Sonic 2 is the only game to give a bonus upon collecting all rings in one act: http://info.sonicretro.org/Perfect_Bonus (and there are bonus points for collecting all rings in Sonic 3 special stage).

Comment: @Wilerson Good point, but not relevant here since there aren't >=300 rings in the level.

Comment: @GnomeSlice Also, in Sonic Chaos, 100 rings give you the bonus stage. I don't know if any other sonic game use this same mechanics for the bonus.

Comment: @DenilsonSáMaia Sonic Spinball required you to collect all of the rings in a stage to get to the special stage. http://sonic.wikia.com/wiki/Bonus_Stage_(Sonic_the_Hedgehog_Spinball)